# Can't you use the keyword 'base' in a webmethod in .Net

Tags: c#, master-pages, void, webmethod

In `masterpage` c# I have set this `public void`:

```
public void mtwelcomeuser()
{
    //Code to set instance of masterpage...
}
```

I need recovery the instance set in `masterpage` on `webmethod`:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod]
public static void Savep(p tlco)
{
   //recovery the instance set in masterpage
}
```

I'm trying to use the `base` keyword in a `webmethod`, but the compiler won't allow me to use it.

Why not?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod]
public static void Savep(p tlco)
{
   ((Masterpage)base.Master).mtwelcomeuser();
}
```

Comment: It's a static method which can't have a base method. There is no inheritance involved here.

Comment: @Lennart No solution ?

Comment: One solution is to avoid `static` in web apps. It does not scale and is not recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe solution.

I hope I was helpful.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        UserIsAuthenticated();
        string CurrentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        Response.Write(CurrentUser.ToString().ToUpper() + "<br />");
    }
}

public static bool UserIsAuthenticated()
{
    bool isAuthenticated = false;
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Length != 0)
            {
               //...
            }
        }
    }
    catch { } // not Authenticated
    return isAuthenticated;
}
```